Use cases of logical data centers in Apache Cassandra
Note: I am very new to Apache Cassandra. So this question might be a basic one but I am not able to find any appropriate answer on the internet, thus asking here.
I was reading about how replication happens in Cassandra. Cassandra supports the concept of logical data centres. These are data centres which may not actually be in separate geographic physical locations.
I wanted to understand what are the use cases of using such logical data centres. To me, the whole concept of data centres seems to have any advantage only if they are actually geographically separated so that the overall system can be more fault tolerant and performant.
Any help regarding this highly appreciated. Thanks

Welcome to Stack Overflow! A friendly reminder that this site is for getting help with coding, algorithm, or programming language problems so I voted to have your post moved to DBA Stack Exchange. For future reference, you should post DB admin/ops questions on https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/ask?tags=cassandra. Cheers!

The main use case for splitting nodes into logical DCs (vs physical or geographical DCs) is for load isolation.
Think of systems where there are different functionalities where you want to separate one function from another. In an ecommerce site for example, DC1 is where customer transactions are handled (customer logins, browsing catalogues, purchasing) while DC2 is used exclusively used for reporting and inventory management.
By separating the workloads into their own DCs, you can make sure that analytics workloads like monthly reporting don't affect the performance of online (OLTP) workloads. Cheers!
